# How to proper reference aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 from Visual Studio/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, runtime

I got ASP.NET Core 3.1 web-app which is deployed to Ubuntu 18.04.

The runtime should reference Debian package aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 in order to get updates automatically on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, the Visual Studio project needs to have references to nuget packages Microsoft.AspNetCore, etc.. in order to be buildable.

After publishing and creating DEB Package installer, there are two ASP.NET Core 3.1 runtimes...the one shipped within the application (from nuget packages). And the one installed by Debian Package aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 (defined in Debian control file).

I would probably need to build/publish the project without ASP.Net Core libraries.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Those dependencies Microsoft.AspNetCore.* which can be updated to 3.1.2, update
2. other Microsoft.AspNetCore.* dependencies remove, these are already in Runtime (part of Visual Studio 2019.4.x installation or part of aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 o Ubuntu or MSBuild 16.4)